# Set branch for all Git Submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a command to set the same branch name for all *existing* Git Submodules

```
git submodule add -b develop *
```

Basically I need a way to recursively set the branch for each module in the `.gitmodules` file.

Answer (score 15):

> Looking for a way to recursive set the branch in the .gitmodules file

With Git 2.22 (Q2 2019, four years later), you will be able to use `git submodule set-branch -b <abranch>`, because `git submodule` learns `set-branch` subcommand that allows the
`submodule.*.branch` settings to be modified.

See [commit b57e811](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b57e8119e6e08f731308923ef2b033eb45152bc6), [commit c89c494](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c89c494240a516b082f397130ae44df2e757866b) (08 Feb 2019), and [commit 7a4bb55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a4bb55f3a47756b5cd9ca2d120c7fe119439e81) (07 Feb 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 01f8d78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01f8d78887d45dc10f29d3926d5cc52f78838846), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `submodule`: teach `set-branch` subcommand

> This teaches `git-submodule` the `set-branch` subcommand which allows the branch of a submodule to be set through a porcelain command without having to manually manipulate the `.gitmodules` file.

In your case, for *all* submodules, using [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt):

```
git submodule foreach 'git submodule set-branch --branch aBranch -- ${sm_path}'
git submodule foreach 'git submodule set-branch --default -- ${sm_path}'
```

(the last line set the `master` branch, [which is the default](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a4bb55f3a47756b5cd9ca2d120c7fe119439e81))

---

Before Git 2.22, you would use the command I mentioned in "[How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)"

```
 git submodule foreach 'git config -f .gitmodules submodule.${sm_path}.branch <branch>'
```

---

Note: Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) makes clear the `--default` and `--branch` options are mutually exclusive.

See [commit 40e747e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40e747e89d247b3a12e6cddf848d145bf403a72c) (16 Sep 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7f17913](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f17913161ef06fb983f02fae02fc580863cd605), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

Comment: how do you get ${sm_path}? Is that from foreach?

When I try your command: 

git submodule foreach 'git submodule set-branch --branch development -- ${sm_path}'

I get this error: fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for api

api is one of my submodules

Comment: @JoshuaDyck It is set by `git submodule foreach`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt. What version of Git are you using? On which OS and which shell? Are you using it from the root folder of the parent repo hosting those submodules?

Comment: I installed the latest from git-scm.com which was 2.21. That must be it. I assumed the latest release would have it. But as you stated above it is 2.22. How would you go about getting 2.22 if git-scm.com only has 2.21? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaDyck Correct. You now have the 2.22rc0 for you to test.

Comment: hi @VonC I just installed Git 2.23 in windows and have same problems as Joshua...

Comment: @YaP Can you try with a simple echo? I did so two days ago without issue in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58667195/6309, as a concrete example.

Comment: how can I leverage the --depth 1 here ?  I cant get this to work

Comment: @MartinKosicky What version of Git are you using? And what " I cant get this to work" means? Is there an error message?

Comment: It seems that it still is trying to fetch master, unles i invoke git submodule update --remote . therefore the correct branch has to be upfront pulled (and --depth 1 strips that out on the first update --init)

Comment: @VonC more importantly, I cannot get the right combination of operations to work to track remote branch on submodule with shallow init,   I am using git submodule update --remote --init --depth 1 ,  but that doesnt work with --depth 1,  without it it works. I have newest git i think 2.26.2

Comment: @MartinKosicky OK. Can you ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @VonC oki https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483547/how-to-shallow-pull-submodule-that-is-tracked-by-branch-name

Answer (score 4):

See [`git submodule foreach`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.

```
git submodule foreach git checkout -b develop
```

Comment: Looking for a way to recursive set the branch in the .gitmodules file. Updated to clarify