# Changing an existing submodule's branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I initially added my submodule, I specified a particular branch, as seen in the `.gitmodule` file:

```
[submodule "externals/grpc/grpc"]
    path = externals/grpc/grpc
    url = git@github.com:me/grpc.git
    branch = release-1.0
```

I want to change to the master branch of my submodule, so I changed the branch in `.gitmodules` from `release-1.0` to `master`, and for good measure, just deleted the submodule from my parent git tree:

```
cd $submodules
rm -rf grpc
cd $gitroot
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Now, when I go back to my submodule, it's still checked out from a commit on the `release-1.0` branch, not the latest master commit.

What steps am I missing to switch my submodule's branch?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Go into the directory where the submodule resides and `git checkout` the correct branch/commit. Then go up one level and `git add` and `git commit` the directory. This will check in the submodule with the correct commit.

And don't forget to run `git submodule update --recursive` on the other clients after updating them.

Comment: It is interesting that while git still points to the right commit (in the branch), the `.gitmodules` file does not include the branch field. It seems to work regardless of that, though.

Comment: .gitmodules shows the branch you initially checked out. It is not updated when you change the branch, and has no effect. The actual branch you are on is stored int he submodule itself, not in this file - fwiw.

Answer (score 35):

**If you want to switch to a branch you've never tracked before.**

After you have changed the branch in `.gitmodules`, do the following:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
cd submodule_name
git checkout new_branch_name
```

Comment: For me the first line (git update) was enough

Comment: This almost worked for me. My error message included the line `Unable to find current origin/origin/main revision in submodule path`. My `.gitmodules` had the branch as `branch = origin/main`, so I changed it to just `branch = main`, then all was well.

Answer (score 33):

Since v2.22(Q3 2019) (thanks to @VonC in comments)

Suppose you have submodule `xyz`, the `.gitmodules` looks like

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "xyz"]
        path = xyz
        url = git@git.com:xyz.git
        branch = main
```

And you can check it with

```
$ git config --file=.gitmodules -l
submodule.xyz.path=xyz
submodule.xyz.url=git@git.com:xyz.git
submodule.xyz.branch=main
```

Now you want to ref branch `v1.0.0` for `xyz`, you can run

```
git submodule set-branch -b v1.0.0 xyz
```

Then run for brand new update

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

Comment: Note: it was [introduced with Git 2.22 (Q3 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885186/6309).

Comment: `git submodule sync` is what I was missing (not mentioned in a number of other answers)!

Answer (score 8):

The answer above (@milgner) didn't work me (git version 2.17.0). Maybe I did something wrong.

The below is what worked for me:

```
nano .gitmodules # substitute the needed branch here
git submodule update submodule_name # update the submodule
git add .gitmodules && git commit -m 'some comment' # add and commit
git submodule status # check that changes have been applied
```