# How to switch git submodule with other branch properly?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have repo, which contain lots of submodules. Every submodule was initialized with `-b branch_rev_1`. I want to switch state of this repo, changing every submodule's branch with `-b branch_rev_2` (so I will be able to build app with different revision of dependencies).

But making `checkout -b branch_rev_2` inside submodule's directory does not change record in `.gitmodules` file.
Is there any way for switch state of all submodules after changing branch name in `.gitmodules` file (or vice versa, sync `.gitmodules` description and other configuration in .git folder after checking out specific revision inside submodule) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit `.gitmodules` manually (using an editor) or using `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<name>.branch <branch_name>`. After modifying sync it to `.git/config` with the command `git submodule sync` and update submodules using `git submodule update --init --remote`.

Comment: Using `git config -f .gitmodules` didn't work for me, the .gitmodules file did not update. I had to use the solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73474931/5488464

Comment: @fishlein What was exact command? `git config -f .gitmodules` is not enough, it must be something like `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<name>.branch <branch_name>`

Comment: Thanks, that is clearer. I was under the impression that the command would take the branch that the submodule is currently checked out to (`branch_rev_2` in the OP's question), but actually you are suggesting to manually overwrite the file, which will ignore whatever has been checked out in the submodule. It think you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: @fishlein Tnx, I updated the answer a bit. "*…take the branch that the submodule is currently checked out to…*" That could be scripted — get the checked out branch, set it in `.gitmodules`. The answer you linked above (`git submodule set-branch -b v1.0.0 xyz`) does the same — set the branch to a fixed name, not to the checked out branch name.