# Changing git module branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

I'm using `git submodule` in order to track a subproject. The submodule points at a specific branch, but I now need to change it.

I've tried to manually edit the `.gitmodules` file and change the `branch =` entry, but every command to update the repo I give later doesn't do anything or fails.

I've tried

```
git submodule sync # Succeeds, but nothing happens
git submodule update # Doesn't do anything
git submodule update --remote # fails with Needed a single revision
```

The subproject did correctly check out and gitk in there shows that it does indeed have the new branch that I need to switch to. I could do this manually and commit the new hash but I'm not sure whether `git submodule` would truly understand the change this way.

I've also tried deleting all submodule folders (including inside the `.git` folder) and re-running

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

But I still get the project to the same state as before (I assume because it's still updating to the committed hash).

Comment: The "Needed a single revision" error usually means that the configured branch name in `.gitmodules` wasn't found in the submodule's `origin`. Have you checked that the configured branch isn't misspelled?

Answer (score 11):

Clone again, and then:

- change branch inside your submodule

  ```
     cd submodule
     git checkout -b anotherBranch
     # if it is a new branch, push it first.
     git push -u origin anotherBranch
  ```

Then reflect that change in the parent repo:

```
    cd ..

    git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<pathToSubmodule>.branch anotherbranch
    # or, since Git 2.22 (Q2 2019)
    git submodule set-branch --branch anotherbranch -- path/To/Submodule

    git add .
    git commit -m "record new gilink, and modified .gitmodules"
    git push
```

Try then to clone again your parent repo to check everything is as expected.

(Again, Git 2.22, Q2 2019, has [introduced `git submodule set-branch --branch aBranch -- <submodule_path>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885186/6309))