# Git add remotes to submodules recursively

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo located on my machine at `/path/to/repo`, which contains several submodules, `/path/to/repo/submoduleA` and `/path/to/repo/foo/bar/submoduleB`.

Due to a workflow that I cannot change, the git repo gets copied (as in scp -r) to a remote server, where I work on the code.  I want to pull the changes back to the original machine.  Cloning/pushing from the remote server isn't an option.

It is tedious to go to each submodule and do

`git remote add <name> <url>:/server/path/to/repo/<path to submodule>`

Is there a faster way?  Something magical like

`git remote add --submodules <name> <url>:/server/path/to/repo`

executed from the top-level repo that will recurse to each submodule and add the appropriate relative path onto the remote of each submodule?  `git remote --help` doesn't show anything useful, and neither the [Git Pro Book section on submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

My best guess is something like

`git submodule foreach 'git remote add <name> <url>:/server/path/to/repo/...'`

might work, if there there is a way to replace the `...` with the loop-dependent relative path of each submodule in that foreach.  I just don't know of such a mechanism built into `git submodule foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) does include a list of variables which should help:

> The command has access to the variables:

- `$name`: the name of the relevant submodule section in `.gitmodules`,
- `$sm_path`: the path of the submodule as recorded in the immediate superproject,
- `$displaypath`: contains the relative path from the current working directory to the submodules root directory,
- `$sha1`: the commit as recorded in the immediate superproject, and
- `$toplevel`: the absolute path to the top-level of the immediate superproject.

So in your case:

```
git submodule foreach 'git remote add $name <url>:/server/path/to/repo/$sm_path'
```

`$displaypath` would  replace the `...` with the loop-dependent relative path of each submodule.
But, as noted by the [OP waldol1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2383529/waldol1) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666630/git-add-remotes-to-submodules-recursively/58667195#comment103638712_58667195), `$sm_path` is a fixed value, as opposed to a relative path.

Example with [`docker/docker.github.io`](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io), executed in the *subfolder* `tests`:

```
D:\git\docker.github.io\tests>git submodule foreach "echo $displaypath"
Entering 'src/github.com/gdevillele/frontparser'
src/github.com/gdevillele/frontparser

vs.

D:\git\docker.github.io\tests>git submodule foreach "echo $sm_path"
Entering 'src/github.com/gdevillele/frontparser'
tests/src/github.com/gdevillele/frontparser
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.  Just to double check my understanding, if I execute the foreach from `/path/to/repo`, then $sm_path == $diplaypath, right?  But if I execute it from a different directory, then they aren't equal, but $sm_path is what I'd need, so wouldn't it be more flexible to just do `git submodule foreach 'git remote add $name <url>:/server/path/to/repo/$sm_path'`?

Comment: @waldol1 I confirm your understanding, and I have edited the answer accordingly, with an example.