# git - error after changing submodules URL - fatal: Needed a single revision

Tags: git, git-submodules

I downloaded a module from github. But instead of using the github repository, I initialized my own and pushed all the code to my own bitbucket remote repository with one "initial commit".

But I would like to use the github repo, so that it is easier to keep it up to date. So I opened `.gitmodules` and changed the URL of the repo, made a commit and pushed.

But if I execute `git clone myrepo_url.git` and then execute `git submodule --init --update --remote` then everything is fine, but the module where I changed the URL.

```
> fatal: Needed a single revision, unable to find commit of
> origin/master in Submodul-path 'app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager'
```

Thats maybe because my old repository used `master` as the main branch and the github repository uses `1.x`.

**.git/modules/app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager/config**:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        worktree = ../../../../../../app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "1.x"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/1.x
```

**.gitmodules**

```
[submodule "app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager"]
        path = app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
        url = https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager.git
```

How can I fix this so that the error does not show if I clone the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add branch information to the file **.gitmodule**

```
[submodule "app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager"]
        path = app/code/EthanYehuda/CronjobManager
        url = https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager.git
        branch = 1.x
```

Now there were no errors

(Git 2.22, Q2 2019, has introduced

[`git submodule set-branch --branch aBranch -- <submodule_path>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885186/6309))

So always lookup the main branch first and add it with the above command, after calling

```
git submodule add <git-url.git> <name-of-module>
```

Comment: Or you can remove `--remote` from `git submodule --init --update --remote`, eg use `git submodule --init --update` and it won't require a branch configuration for the submodule.