# How can I push my commit if I have "HEAD detached from" error on linux command line?

Tags: git

I did changes on submodule and wanted to make pull request.

But currently getting "following Head detached from xxxx" error and I cant push it.

Do you know how can I solve it?

[image: Error]

```
HEAD detached from a9cd50a
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: You can't do anything from a detached head state; all you can do is look around. You need to turn this into, or return to, an actual branch.

Comment: It's not an error. You can use `HEAD` to refer to it. To push the detached head to the branch `foo`, use `git push origin HEAD:foo`. If the push results in an error about non-fast-forward, use `git pull origin foo` or `git pull origin -r foo` before a next push.

Answer (score 0):

A submodule is [always checked out as detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/6309), unless you [set the relevant configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36375256/6309):

- `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<submodule-path>.branch <branch>`
- or [since Git 2.22, Q2 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309):
  [`git submodule set-branch --branch aBranch -- <submodule_path>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885186/6309))

From the submodule folder, you can:

- list its remote branches: `git fetch` + `git branch -avv`
- switch to a new PR branch of your choice: `git switch -c a_new_PR`
- add your commit, and push (assuming you have the right to push to the upstream submodule repository, because you are its owner or a member: otherwise, you need to reference as submodule a fork of your own)